# Clojure with-local-vars not creating thread-local bind?

Tags: clojure

In the documentation of `with-local-var`

```
varbinding=> symbol init-expr

Executes the exprs in a context in which the symbols are bound to
vars with per-thread bindings to the init-exprs. The symbols refer
to the var objects themselves, and must be accessed with var-get and
var-set
```

But why `thread-local?` returns false?

```
user=> (with-local-vars [x 1] (thread-bound? #'x))
false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, in your example, `x` is a local binding to a variable containing a `var`.  `#'x` is shorthand for `(var x)`, which will resolve x as a global in the current namespace.  Since `with-local-vars` doesn't affect the *global* `x`, `thread-bound?` returns `false`.

You need to use `x` (not `(var x)`) to refer to the `var` created by `with-local-vars`.  For example:

```
(def x 1)

(with-local-vars [x 2]
  (println (thread-bound? #'x))
  (println (thread-bound? x)))
```

Outputs:

```
false
true
```

Also, note that `with-local-vars` does not dynamically rebind `x`.  `x` is only lexically bound to the new var within the `with-local-vars` block.  If you call a function that refers to `x`, it will refer to the global `x`.

If you want to dynamically rebind `x`, you need to use `binding` and make `x` dynamic:

```
(def ^:dynamic x 1)

(defn print-x []
  (println x))

(with-local-vars [x 2]
  (print-x)) ;; This will print 1

(binding [x 2]
  (print-x)) ;; This will print 2
```